# FluentValidation Custom Validator with placeholders

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

say I've a class Customer like

```
public string RegistrationNr 
public bool Archived
```

I've created a validator

```
internal sealed class AddCustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<AddCustomerViewModel> 
{ 
private readonly ICustomerService _customerService; 
public AddCustomerValidator(ICustomerService customerService) 
{ 
_customerService = customerService;

        RuleFor(c => c.RegistrationNumber)
            .Must((registrationNumber) =>
            {
                var customer = _customerService.FindByRegistrationNumber(registrationNumber);
                return customer == null;
            })
            .WithMessage("Number already in use.");
     }
 }
```

This works fine

Now I'd like to have a more detailed message like 'Number already in use for active customer' or 'Number already in use for archived customer'

I understand I can use placeholders and create a message like

```
.WithMessage("Number already in use for {0} customer.")
```

but I don't understand how to get the value from customer.

I tried creating CustomValidators but got stuck on that

Many questions I find on this problem refer to older versions, I use 11.6.0

I came up with

```
public static class MyCustomValidators
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> RegistrationNumberExists<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> rulebuilder)
    {
        return rulebuilder.Must((rootObject, registrationNumber, context) =>
        {
            var customer =  _customerService.FindByRegistrationNumber(AfvoerCheckCommon.Formatters.Formatter.FormatRegNr(registrationNumber));
            if (customer == null)
                return true;
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ArchiveOrAactive", customer.Archived ? "archived" : "active");
            return false;
        })
        .WithMessage("Number already in use for {ArchiveOrAactive} customer.");
    }
}
```

But i does not recognize the customerservice, can I pass or inject it?

Comment: On first glance, I would have said, too: use a custom validator. Can you add your best attempt at that and why it doesn't work for you? Maybe we can fix it.

Comment: Added attempt with error

Comment: Found a way to resolve this. I use  this in a MVVM solution. The framework , Catel, gave me an option to retrieve it from the registered service. I changed th call to  RuleFor(c => c.RegistrationNumber)                
                .RegistrationNumberExists(); and it works

Answer (score 0):

I find the doc https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/configuring.html

```
//Referencing other property values:
```

RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname)
.NotNull()
.WithMessage(customer => $"This message references some other properties: Forename: {customer.Forename} Discount: {customer.Discount}");